# How to configurate ORMLite's Table Config File in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, configuration-files, ormlite

The documentation (http://ormlite.com/docs/table-config) says:

> You will need to run this utility locally on your development box (not
>   in an Android device), whenever you make a change to one of your data
>   classes. This means that right now, this must be done by hand to keep
>   the configuration file in sync with your database classes. **To run the
>   utility you will need to use the local Java runtime environment (JRE).
>   Under eclipse, edit the "Run Configuration" for the utility, select
>   the JRE tab, and select an alternative JRE (1.5 or 1.6). Your
>   project’s JRE should be undefined since it is an Android application.
>   You’ll also need to remove the Android bootstrap entry from the
>   Classpath tab.**

But it's not clear for me. No need to configure JRE tab in Android? How to remove the Android bootstrap entry from the Classpath tab?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved:

1. Go to *Run*->*Run Configurations*->*Java Application*->*Right Mouse Button*->*New*.
2. In *Name* type a name for your configuration.
3. In *Project browse* to the Android project select it and click *OK*.
4. In *Main Class* browse to the *DatabaseConfigUtil* class *(which extends *OrmLiteConfigUtil*)* select it and click *OK*.
5. Click on the *JRE* tab and choose the 1.5 or 1.6 JRE.
6. Press the *Classpath* tab, Select the Bootstrap Entries *(in my case Android 4.4)* and click *Remove*.
7. Click *Apply*.